# MySQL Fulltext search present me inaccurate result

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, rows

Let's say that I have a database that looks like this (`MyISAM`):

```
+------------+-------------------+------------------+
| student_id | student_firstname | student_lastname |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+
|         30 | Patrik            | Andersson        |
|         79 | Patrik            | Svensson         |
+------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

And I perform this query:

```
SELECT s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname FROM students s
WHERE MATCH (student_firstname, student_lastname) 
 AGAINST 
('+Patrik Svensson*' IN BOOLEAN mode)
```

This generates both of the above rows. Why do I not get 1 row in my result? Is it because the last three letters in the `student_lastname` are the same? Is there any way to make `FULLTEXT` more precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested it, this query is giving right result

```
SELECT s.student_firstname, s.student_lastname FROM students s
WHERE MATCH (student_firstname, student_lastname) 
 AGAINST 
('+Patrik +Svensson*' IN BOOLEAN mode)
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried reading the MySQL documentation?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html

And I quote:

> By default (when neither + nor - is specified) the word is optional,
>   but the rows that contain it are rated higher.

And:

> '+apple macintosh'
>
> Find rows that contain the word “apple”, but rank rows higher if they
>   also contain “macintosh”.

Comment: That was weird, because if I remove the + I get an even more inaccurate result (more rows).